# XSD to XML Converter

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, xsd, converters

I am trying to convert an XSD file into its corresponding XML document.  Using IntelliJ's built-in tool makes this easy but something is wrong.  It seems to be creating everything properly, and this is a large XSD, but on closer inspection, some elements are missing.  The specific XSD I am using is from here: https://www.iata.org/contentassets/76a4543036794d59ad747f3d80bb9792/19.2-schemas-edist.zip.  File is called IATAAirShoppingRS.xsd.
Here is a snippet of the file.  After CarrierOffersSummary, there are supposed to be more elements that are created and expanded but there are just comments.

```
<iata:TotalAmount CurCode="token">1000.00</iata:TotalAmount>
          </iata:TotalPrice>
          <!--Optional:-->
          <iata:ValidatingCarrierCode>token</iata:ValidatingCarrierCode>
          <!--Optional:-->
          <iata:WebAddressURL>http://www.corp.com/pater/regina</iata:WebAddressURL>
        </iata:ALaCarteOffer>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <iata:CarrierOffersSummary>
          <!--Optional:-->
          <iata:HighestOfferPrice>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <iata:LoyaltyUnitAmount CurCode="token">1000.00</iata:LoyaltyUnitAmount>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <iata:LoyaltyUnitName>token</iata:LoyaltyUnitName>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <iata:TotalAmount CurCode="token">1000.00</iata:TotalAmount>
          </iata:HighestOfferPrice>
          <!--Optional:-->
          <!--Optional:-->
        </iata:CarrierOffersSummary>
        <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
        <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
      </iata:CarrierOffers>
    </iata:OffersGroup>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
    <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
    <!--Optional:-->
    <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
```

I appreciate any help provided.

Comment: Providing an XSD without an XML sample is one of the worst practices in B2B communication.  It's really a shame that people don't include sample XML with every XSD.  It's like sending a blue-print and telling customers to build it themselves, and we'll tell you when it's wrong.

Comment: Examples are often useful, but I think your claim is too broad. Sometimes an XSD, if it is carefully designed, only allows valid and meaningful documents (those two are not the same).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to the 'Zero or mor repeatitions' comments?

I have not used IntelliJ's tool, but the Eclipse XML example document generator has settings to control the output, including whether anything gets generated for optional (minOccurs="0") elements. I suggest that you look at the documentation for the IntelliJ tool to see whether it has similar settings.
However...

> I am trying to convert an XSD file into its corresponding XML document.

For most XSDs, especially large and complex ones, there is no such thing. Any non-trivial XSD describes a whole family of XML documents. If you are using this tool to generate unit test data then *be very careful about functional coverage*. You should not trust any automated tool to generate useful data for your testing - that requires an understanding of the business requirements for your project.

Comment: I thought it might be that but there are other places where it is generating elements with that comment correctly:

<!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                    <iata:EmailAddress>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <iata:ContactTypeText>string</iata:ContactTypeText>
                        <iata:EmailAddressText>string</iata:EmailAddressText>
                    </iata:EmailAddress>
I'm not using the xml to test.  I am using it as a template for api calls.
Tool comes with IntelliJ and there doesn't seem to be a way to configure it.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the example data that the generator has produced. Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: The data is not wrong.  I don't care about the sample data that it is generating, I care about the Xml document.  I am using that xml document as a template to replace values in and make soap api calls with.  It generated 2600 lines but is missing some XML elements so I assume there is a bug, or some setting that limits how much data it is processing.  Considering this is an Intellij default plugin, I don't see any configs I can tweak.

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with the XML document that the generator has produced. It is consistently generating example tags for mandatory elements (minOccurs >=1). It is generating a comment for elements which are optional (minOccurs=0). This is not a bug, it is just how the generator works, and it seems perfectly reasonable to me. I think you should reconsider your approach to this problem (and it would have helped if you had explained your objective in the question)

Comment: Thanks for looking into this.  Did you happen to use Intellij and use the XSD i provided to generate the XML?  If you did, do you not see missing elements?

Comment: I did not use IntelliJ. I did download the xsd and look at it. The elements that you claim are 'missing' are all optional (minOccurs=0).

Comment: Yea that's what I tried to explain.  Most of the optional elements are there but some are not, so the behavior is inconsistent

Answer (score 0):

As @kimbert points out, this is happening because the xsd file allows zero occurrences of these fields, and the generator is being lazy by taking that route. The quick and dirty solution to force Intellij to generate at least one element for each of these fields is to create a copy of the xsd, and in that copy, replace all occurrences of `minOccurs="0"` with `minOccurs="1"`, which is easy with Intellij's [replace all in file](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Finding_and_Replacing_Text_in_File.html) tool. Then you can generate your xml from that new xsd and at least one entry will be created for each field.